Adding Firebase into my Swift Package giving me Package resolution failed
This is the package.swift file.
// swift-tools-version: 5.10
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "TestKit",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, making them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "TestKit",
            targets: ["TestKit"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "5.9.1")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "10.24.0"))
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
        .target(
            name: "TestKit",
            dependencies: [
                .byName(name: "Alamofire")
            ]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "TestKitTests",
            dependencies: ["TestKit"]),
    ]
)

When I add targets -> target -> dependencies -> .byName(name: "Firebase") into package.swift. It starts giving me error that Package resolution failed; see package resolution log for details
and Without adding .byName(name: "Firebase"), it give No such module 'Firebase' on import Firebase.
Note: I am succefull to import Alamofire

This line solved my problem .product(name: "FirebaseAnalytics", package: "firebase-ios-sdk")

What's in the package resolution log?
